# Are these two bjt amplifiers the same?

Tags: bjt

Is the circuit on the left the same as the circuit on the right?

I think that they are..what do you think?
[image]

Edit : The white dot in the right one is nothing btw,just sloppy drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - they are.

What makes you question that they are the same?

A schematic describes the interconnection of components.  How it is arranged makes no difference to the schematic although it will affect how easily it can be interpreted.  The whole point of a schematic is so that the circuit can be understood.

Both of these schematics follow the general rules: positive at the top, signal flow from left to right. I would tend to put the base pointing to the left as in the first circuit but the other is acceptable.